# Yum Notification Script

Tags: beginner, bash, linux, email, scheduled-tasks

This is a Bash script I wrote to email me when updates are available for my server. I'm new to bash programming, so I don't know if I've done this well.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copyright 2016 FlyingPiMonster
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS RELEASED "AS IS", WITH NO WARRANTY OR GUARANTEE OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. THE DEVELOPER IS NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE
# CAUSED BY THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
#
# All rights reserved.
#


# Set up argument variables

reload_cron=false
print_help=false
quiet_mode=false
print_config=false

# Read arguments using getopts

while getopts ":rhqd" opts; do
    case "$opts" in
    r)
        reload_cron=true ;;
    \?|h)
        print_help=true ;;
    q)
        quiet_mode=true ;;
    d)
        print_config=true ;;
    esac
done


# Set up default configuration options
typeset -A config
config=(
    [EmailFrom]="YumNotifier"
    [EmailRecipient]="root@localhost"
    [EmailSubject]="Updates available for your computer"
    [EmailTitle]="Updates Available"
    [EmailGreeting]="YumNotifier has detected updates for some software on your computer."
    [EmailSignature]="Thank you for using YumNotifier!"
    [HideUpdateDetails]="No"
    [EmailHiddenUpdateText]="Please login with SSH and use the yum command to install these updates."
    [RunFrequency]="DAILY"
    [UserId]="root"
    [ErrorBadConfigurationOption]='The following configuration option is not set correctly:'
    [ErrorWritingCrontab]="Could not write to crontab file"
    [ErrorSendingMail]="An error occurred while sending mail"
    [MessageNoUpdatesAvailable]="No updates available"
)

# Read configuration file

while read -r line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -F = | grep "^[^#]" | &>/dev/null; then
        varname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
        config["$varname"]=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2)
    fi
done < /etc/yumnotifier/yumnotifier.conf


# Check if any flags are set that change the task the program is to do

if [[ "$print_help" == "true" ]]; then
        cat /usr/share/doc/yumnotifier/help.txt
        exit
fi

if [[ "$print_config" == "true" ]]; then
    cat /usr/share/doc/yumnotifier/default.conf
    exit
fi

if [[ "$reload_cron" == "true" ]]; then
    if ! [[ "${config[UserId]}" =~ ^[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?$ ]]; then
        if [[ "$quiet_mode" == "false" ]]; then
            echo "${config[ErrorBadConfigurationOption]} UserId (${config[UserId]})"
        fi
        exit 78
    fi

    crontask=''
    case "${config[RunFrequency]}" in
        HOURLY) crontask='0 * * * *' ;;
        DAILY) crontask='* 0 * * *' ;;
        WEEKLY) crontask='* * * * 0' ;;
        MONTHY) crontask='* * 0 * *' ;;
        NEVER) exit ;;
        *)
            if [[ "$quiet_mode" == "false" ]]; then
                echo "${config[ErrorBadConfigurationOption]} RunFrequency"
            fi
            exit 78
            ;;
    esac

    (echo "$crontask ${config[UserId]} yumnotifier" > /etc/cron.d/yumnotifier.cron) &>/dev/null
    code="$?"

    if [[ "$code" != 0 ]]; then
        if [[ "$quiet_mode" == "false" ]]; then
                    echo "${config[ErrorWritingCrontab]}"
                fi
        exit 1
    fi

        exit
fi


# Read from yum check-updates. If HideUpdateDetails is set to Yes, we only need to read the exit code of the command; otherwise, loop through it and print a table.

lines=$(yum --quiet check-update)
code="$?"

# If yum check-update returns 0, there are no updates available
if [[ "$code" == 0 ]]; then
    if [[ "$quiet_mode" == "false" ]]; then
        echo "${config[MessageNoUpdatesAvailable]}"
    fi
    exit
fi

# Create variable for update description
maintext=""

if [[ "${config[HideUpdateDetails]}" == "No" ]]; then
    maintext+="<table>"

    while read -r line; do
            if ! [[ "$line" =~ [A-Za-z]*[\ ]Packages ]]; then
                    name=$(echo "$line" | tr -s '\t' | cut -f 1 | cut -d '.' -f 1)
            maintext+="<tr><th>${name}</th></tr>\n"
            fi
    done <<< "$lines"
    maintext+="</table>"
else
    maintext+="${config[EmailHiddenUpdateText]}"
fi


# Start creating email body

body="<html><head></head><body>"
body+="<h1 style='background-color: black; color: white;'>${config[EmailTitle]}<span style='color: black'>:&nbsp;</span></h1>" # The :&nbsp; is to prevent bad formatting in the text-only summary most mail clients provide
body+="<p>${config[EmailGreeting]}</p>"
body+="$maintext"
body+="<p>${config[EmailSignature]}</p>"
body+="</body></html>"

# Send email

echo -e "Content-Type: text/html\nSubject:${config[EmailSubject]}\n$body" | sendmail -F "${config[EmailFrom]}" "${config[EmailRecipient]}" &>/dev/null

code="$?"

if [[ "$code" != 0 ]]; then
    if [[ "$quiet_mode" == "false" ]]; then
        echo "${config[ErrorSendingMail]}"
    fi
    exit 1;
fi
```

And here's the default config file. Everything is commented out because the values are also hardcoded.

```
################################################################################
## This is the default configuration file for YumNotifier. All valid
## configuration options are listed here; to edit an option, uncomment the line
## and edit its value. Some options may require running yumnotifier -r to take
## effect.
################################################################################



#### EMAIL SETTINGS

## The string to put in the "To:" field of all emails
#EmailFrom=YumNotifier

## The email address to send notifications to
#EmailRecipient=root@localhost

## The subject line of notification emails
#EmailSubject=Updates are available for your computer

## The heading inside the notification email
#EmailTitle=Updates Available

## A message to put at the beginning of each notification email
#EmailGreeting=YumNotifier has detected updates for some software on your computer.

## A message to put at the end of each notification email
#EmailSignature=Thank you for using YumNotifier!

## If this is set to No, a full list of software to be updated will be sent in
##  the email. If it is set to anything else, the string in
##  EmailHiddenUpdateText will be sent instead of the names of the packages.
#HideUpdateDetails=No

## The text to send in the email instead of a list of packages if
##  HideUpdateDetails is not set to No
#EmailHiddenUpdateText=Please login with SSH and use the yum command to install these updates.



#### RUN SETTINGS

### IMPORTANT: When any of the options in this section is updated, you must run
###  yumnotifier -r for it to take effect.

## How often YumNotifier should check for updates. Must be one of HOURLY, DAILY,
##  WEEKLY, MONTHLY, or NEVER. If NEVER is selected, YumNotifier will only run
##  when invoked directly. This is useful for configuring custom cron jobs.
#RunFrequency=DAILY

## The user ID that yumnotifier should run under. It is recommended that you
##  change this from "root" to a user with fewer privileges.
#UserId=root



#### ERROR AND INFORMATION MESSAGES

## The error message to output if a configuration option is invalid
#ErrorBadConfigurationOption=The following configuration option is not set correctly:

## The error message to output if the crontab file is not accessible
#ErrorWritingCrontab=Could not write to crontab file

## The error message to output if the mailer fails to send a notification
#ErrorSendingMail="An error occurred while sending mail"

## The message to output if no updates are available
#MessageNoUpdatesAvailable=No updates available
```

I'm mostly concerned about security issues, but I'll take any advice you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No violations on [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/#), nicely done!
I do have a couple of recommendations.

#### Splitting a line in two

This is an inefficient way to split a line into two parts:

> ```
> varname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
> config["$varname"]=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2)
> ```

Two subshells, `echo` and `cut` processes in each.
It would be better to use pattern substitution instead,
staying within the same process:

```
varname=${line%%=*}
config["$varname"]=${line##*=}
```

But there is a caveat. If there are multiple `=` signs on the line,
this will not take the 2nd column like `cut` does.
However, if that's a serious concern, it's possible to work around that with a few more intermediary substitutions.

The point is to execute as few programs as possible in the process.

#### Shortening the pipeline

For the same reason as in the previous point,
it's good to keep pipelines short.
For example here, the two `grep` commands could be combined:

> ```
> if echo "$line" | grep -F = | grep "^[^#]" | &>/dev/null; then
> ```

Like this:

```
if echo "$line" | grep "^[^#].*=" | &>/dev/null; then
```

One less process to execute.

The `echo` can also be removed by using a here-string instead:

```
if grep "^[^#].*=" <<< "$line" | &>/dev/null; then
```

What is that last `|` doing there before the redirection?
It seems unnecessary.

#### Redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` of `grep`

`&>/dev/null` after the `grep` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`.
But does `grep` ever produce something on `stderr`?
I've never seen it.
So I think the only practical concern is `stdout`.
There's a flag `-q` to make that easy,
so the line can be simplified to:

```
if grep -q "^[^#].*=" <<< "$line"; then
```

#### The `==` operator of `[[ ... ]]`

The `==` operator is useful for pattern matching.
When comparing to a literal string,
it's slightly clearer to use `=` instead.
So instead of this:

> ```
> if [[ "$print_help" == "true" ]]; then
> ```

I recommend this:

```
if [[ "$print_help" = "true" ]]; then
```

#### Magic numbers and strings

`exit 78` appears twice. I suggest putting 78 in a variable,
so that if you ever need to change it, you can do it in one place.

`true` and `false` are magic strings.
It could be a good idea to put those in variables too.

#### Inconsistent indentation

The indentation is inconsistent at places.
It would be better to make it consistent.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I'm confused about is the `==` operator. I usually program in Java, so I'm used to `==`. Why is `=` better here?

Comment: `=` is less powerful than `==`, but it's enough in your case. I think it's best to use the simplest tool that does the job.

Comment: I think I've implemented most of your recommendations ([here's the new file](https://flyingpimonster.net/files/yumnotifier/yumnotifier.txt)). I didn't know that `echo` and `cut` were such performance hits, or anything about substitution. Thanks for reviewing it!

Comment: Executing a process has a non-negligible overhead. In simple scripts with no looping it might not make a difference at all, but if you call several processes in a loop over a few dozen iterations, it becomes very noticeable. It's a good habit to keep process creation to a minimum when you can and easy enough to do.